# After changing MVC project output path, assemblies not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently changed the output path of some of the projects in our MVC website solution to standardize them.  For instance the main projects changed from `bin\` to `bin\x64\Debug\` for the Debug configuration. I changed this via the GUI access by right clicking on the project and selecting properties.

I can rebuild all with no error, but when I start the web app I get:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

...

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/bookshelf/Bookshelf/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\bookshelf\Bookshelf\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
```

It looks as if asp.net / IIS are still looking in the bin folder perhaps?
I have already tried deleting all temp files in user/appdata/local, rebuild all on the solution, and restarting visual studio. I have also tried deleting everything from the .vs folder for the solution, and deleting the csproj.user file for the project.

The dlls are in the bin/x64/Debug folder on the filesystem, as expected from the output path setting.

Comment: Why are you expecting VS to find the assemblies in the `bin\x64\Debug\ ` folder at run-time? It is not looking for them at that location.

Comment: Since changing the output path property, that is where they are ending up when a build occurs.  Is it the convention that the debug build should place them directly in the /bin folder?

Comment: You are confusing two things, namely the location where VS stores the result of the compilation process, and the location where VS searches for necessary assemblies at run-time. They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks as if asp.net / IIS are still looking in the bin folder perhaps?

Of course, that's the location where ASP.NET is looking for assemblies. So make sure that they are located in this folder if you want your web application to work. You cannot possibly expect ASP.NET to be looking in some non standard locations such as `bin\x64\Debug` for example. If you need it to look in some custom locations for assemblies you might need to write a custom assembly loader.

Comment: So output path for Debug builds should just be bin/ ?

Comment: @jackmott For web-apps, yes, it should be.

Comment: Yes that's what should be the output for an ASP.NET application.